# Searching in strings in MQTT Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am sending a string of data in Python Through MQTT.

I am publishing the data on MQTT as..

```
array=["MAC_ADDRESS", True, Sensor_Read()]
publish.single("my/topic", str(array), hostname="test.mosquitto.org")
```

Now i am getting a string on the other side(Subscriber) as

```
['MAC_ADDRESS', True, 23]
```

Now i want to store the data in the separate single variables on the Subscriber side like this

```
m_add= msg.payload[0] , b_add=msg.payload[1], sense_data=msg.payload[2]
```

in this case msg.payload[0] should be "MAC_ADDRESS", msg.payload[1] should be "True" and msg.payload[2] should be "23"...  I am new to python and not able to do that.. if somebody can help me in this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are receiving data as a string, then you can use built-in `json` library to convert it to a list

```
import json
data = "['MAC_ADDRESS', True, 23]"
data_list =  json.loads(data)
```

will give you the list

then you can access the elements of `data_list` as you normally would